# Multiple times URI rewriting using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I wrote rule in .htaccess to rearrange/ rewrite 1st URI into 2nd one (both are given below) but unable to do so still getting 404 (Page Not found errors). I think problem may be in rewrite rule:

1st URI:
http://example.com/post-detail/32/writing-in-the=dark-2001-2nd-edition

2nd URI:
http://example.com/writing-in-the=dark-2001-2nd-edition-t32.html

Here is .htaccess codes:

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)-t([0-9]+).html?$ post-detail/$2/$1  [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Waiting for kind response

Comment: Revision:1st URI: http://example.com/post-detail/32/writing-in-the-dark-2001-2nd-edition
2nd URI: http://example.com/writing-in-the-dark-2001-2nd-edition-t32.html

Answer (score 0):

Your first capture doesn't match the equals sign in the URL, you need to add that into the character class:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-=]+)-t([0-9]+).html?$ post-detail/$2/$1  [QSA,L]
```